# powershell - unwanted delay after start-job

Tags: powershell

Consider following powershell script:

```
$script = {
    Write-Host "Start job: $(Get-Date)"
    1..3 | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "Job count: $_ $(Get-Date)"
        Start-Sleep 1
    }
    Write-Host "Stop job: $(Get-Date)"
}

Write-Host "Start script:  $(Get-Date)"
$job = Start-Job $script
1..10 | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Waiting: $_ $(Get-Date)"
    Receive-Job $job
    Start-Sleep 1
}
Write-Host "Stop script:  $(Get-Date)"
```

and it's output:

```
Start script:  01/08/2014 21:57:44
Waiting: 1 01/08/2014 21:57:44
Waiting: 2 01/08/2014 21:57:45
Waiting: 3 01/08/2014 21:57:46
Waiting: 4 01/08/2014 21:57:47
Start job: 01/08/2014 21:57:46
Job count: 1 01/08/2014 21:57:46
Waiting: 5 01/08/2014 21:57:48
Job count: 2 01/08/2014 21:57:47
Waiting: 6 01/08/2014 21:57:49
Job count: 3 01/08/2014 21:57:48
Waiting: 7 01/08/2014 21:57:50
Stop job: 01/08/2014 21:57:49
Waiting: 8 01/08/2014 21:57:51
Waiting: 9 01/08/2014 21:57:52
Waiting: 10 01/08/2014 21:57:53
```

Why there is 2 seconds delay between starting script and starting job? And how to prevent?

Answer (score 0):

A job runs in a separate Powershell session from your main script.  Creating and initializing that session is going to take some time.  Background jobs are intended for long running tasks.  If the few seconds of time it takes to create the session is significant in your application then it probably isn't a good candidate for running as a background job.